# DateTime Object Not Converting or Displaying Dates

Tags: php, datetime

I have read a few articles on here regarding this and everything is pointing to the fact that this should work. Unless I am missing something simple and just keep over reading it - I can't get this to work. Been editing each bit and re-running for over 2 hours now and really cant see what I'm doing wrong.

```
    $strStart = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $strEnd   = $date_due . " " . $eta; 

    echo $strStart . "<br/>";
    echo $strEnd . "<br/>";

    $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart);
    $dteEnd = new DateTime($strEnd); 

    echo "<br/>";
    echo $dteStart; //nothing printed out
    echo $dteEnd; //nothing printed out
    $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd); 

    echo "<br/>";
    echo $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S"); 

    if ($dteStart > $dteEnd) {
    echo "<br/> place past marker on line....";
    }
```

The code prints out

14-07-2017 19:00:01

14-07-2017 20:57:00

so I know

```
echo $strStart . "<br/>";
echo $strEnd . "<br/>";
```

is running but after converting those strings to DateTime objects the following lines do not print anything

```
echo $dteStart; //nothing printed out
echo $dteEnd; //nothing printed out
```

$date_due and $eta come from a POST and are correctly formatted. 
Checked my PHP version and I am on 5.6 so above the 5.2 needed for DateTime() to be installed. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks.

With this I need to work out if the date and time are past so the date could be the same but the time will be what is the final decider. I have tried what is in 'PHP Check if date is past to a certain date given in a certain format' but that did not solve my issue.

Comment: What are the values of `$date_due` and `$eta`?

Comment: You can compare two DateTime objects with the standard inequality operators.  If one represents "today" and the other represents a different date, the greater-or-less value can be established with if() statements.

Comment: $date_due = 14/07/2017 and $eta = 20:57 then I $eta = $eta . ":00"

Comment: You might want to consider using the ISO-8601 standard representations for dates.  Easier to read, etc.  Looks like 2017-07-14

Comment: I've updated the title to what I think the problem is because I think it is not a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is a better title as I dont know why the DateTime is acting like it holds nothing.

Comment: You're welcome, and I think Ray Paseur is correct. I do not think the constructor for DateTime accepts the date string format you are using. 2017-07-14 19:00:01 will work.

Comment: Also, you should probably use $dteStart->format(...) to see the output.

Comment: I'm trying $strStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); as I need to convert before going in to DateTime I think but not having much luck at the moment. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: ok, now i have the format sorted but I still doesn't function        $strStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$strEnd = $date_due . " " . $eta; 
$strEnd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($strEnd)); and prints out 2017-07-14 20:18:43 / 
2017-07-14 23:15:00

Comment: Sorted it;  $strStart = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$strEnd = $date_due . " " . $eta; 
$strEnd = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($strEnd));

echo $strStart . "<br/>";
echo $strEnd . "<br/>";

if($strStart <= $strEnd) {
  echo "ETA is in the future.<br/>";
}  else {
  echo "ETA is in the past.<br/>";
}

$nowdatetime = new DateTime($strStart);
$etadatetime = new DateTime($strEnd);

$dteDiff  = $nowdatetime->diff($etadatetime); 

echo "<br/>";
echo $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");